# Joomla 2.5: Article Approval before publish Article or page in

Tags: joomla, user-permissions

I Need a help in Joomla, Currently have a website in Joomla 2.5 that's have a 25 Article & will make a new article as per my client input.

I want to **update existing article but not want to publish without client approval** those changes means, if my existing article id is: article&id=101 It's remains after text updated but not want to view this updated text for public user, I am already know about User Groups (Author, Editor, Publisher) but they not able to full fill my requirement like Author can post content but not publish it's good to me but when Author edit this article second time it's automatically publish, here i need help because i want here to administrator approval to this modified text.

Please Help if this can Possible with any Component/Module/Plugin or any trick.

Thanks

Comment: Is it sufficient to unpublish the article when the user edited the article? Or does the revision have been unpublished only but the article should remain published? I think you need a workflow extension for it. Joomla, especially 2.5, doesn't come with this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in core functionality without unpublishing the article first, which I assume you don't want to do. You could duplicate the article (save as copy), revise as an unpublished draft and then swap articles after sign off, but it's not a particularly slick workflow.